# Warning with nftw

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

I'm trying to use the [nftw](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/nftw.html) to process some files under a directory

```
#include <ftw.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 int wrapper(const char * fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf) {
  printf("File %d\n", ftwbuf->base);
  return(0);
} 


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    const char *name;
    int flags = 0;
    name = argv[1];
    nftw(name, wrapper, 20, flags);
    return 0;

}
```

When I'm compiling (gcc kconfig_parser.c -o parser) , I've got this warning and this error..

```
kconfig_parser.c:5: warning: ‘struct FTW’ declared inside parameter list 
kconfig_parser.c:5: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
kconfig_parser.c: In function ‘wrapper’:
kconfig_parser.c:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

I've checked the definition of the struct and the prototype of the callback, and some examples, it should be fine... What am I doing wrong ? (I've removed almost everything of my code to clear it)...

thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Linux, for some reason, still uses SUSv1 for this API, where nftw() is still considered an extension.

From the Linux [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw), the include has to be:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <ftw.h>
```

Comment: Actually, I linked to the SUSv2 specification for how nftw is supposed to work (which I have since updated to the SUSv3 link). On a SUSv2 or SUSv3 compliant system, you shouldn't need that #define, but it looks like you may need it on Linux.

Comment: Brian: In fact, you are right. At the bottom of the new manual page you can read: "Issue 5: Moved from X/OPEN UNIX extension to BASE.". So, it was originally an X/OPEN extension, then moved to base. For some reason, Linux is still using SUSv1 of this API.

Comment: Just a note: the #define needs to be before the inclusion of the first header, even unrelated ones.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Your code works for me. Check your include paths, maybe? Though this is a system header, so it should be pretty hard to miss this. Or were you accidentally compiling a version that didn't have the `#include <ftw.h>` line?

```
$ gcc -o ftw ftw.c
$ ./ftw my-directory
File 10
File 11
File 16
File 16
File 16
File 16
File 16
... etc ...
```

**edit**: The test above was done on Mac OS X. In a (now deleted) comment the OP mentioned he was on Debian, for which [the man page](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=nftw&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+Sid&format=html&locale=en) mentions that `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` is necessary, as Juliano points out.

Answer (score 1):

On a CentOs versions the header file didn't use "#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500"
i had to do this below,

```
#define __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED 1
#include <ftw.h>
```

Comment: Same with Ubuntu, and presumably other Debian based distros. This critical standard UNIX C resource is disabled by default for some crazy reason.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04, this is what seems to work now (similar to CentOS as mentioned by JohnMeg).

`#define __USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED 1
 #include  <ftw.h>`

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer